# На странице не обновляется пагинация - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

```
@if ($posts->lastPage() > 1)
     <div class="clearfix">
            <ul class="pagination" id="pagination-links">
               {{ $posts->links('Pagination.custom') }}
            </ul>
      </div>
@endif
```

Скрипт (jquery 3.6):

```
$(document).ready(function() { $(document).on('change', '#entries', function() {
    var Page = $(this).val();
   
  
    $.ajax({
        url: '/posts',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            Page : Page ,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {   
            console.log(data.posts)               
        }
    });
});
```

Код контроллера:

public function show_posts(Request $request) {

```
    $Page= $request->input('Page', 5);

    $posts= $posts->paginate($Page);
        
     if ($request->ajax()) {
            
            $tableContent = view('Posts', [
                'posts' => $posts,
            ])->render();
            
            return response()->json([
                
                'posts' => $posts,
            ]);
        }

    return view('Posts', [
        'posts' => $posts,
       
    ]);

       
}
```

Я хочу понять, что я делаю не так. Page (выбирается в выпадающем меню #entries) изменяет количество отображаемых постов на одной странице (5, 10, 15 и тд). Когда я меняю Page с 5 на 10, то у меня должно становиться меньше ссылок в пагинации (и наоборот соответственно). Но ничего не происходит, однако console.log(data.posts) отображает все правильно (lastPage там соответствует истине при выбранном Page), в то время как $posts, который в разметке blade.php, вообще никак на изменения не реагирует. Я проверял у него lastPage - оно каким было при загрузке страницы, таким и остается без изменений. Что мне сделать, чтобы пагинация на странице изменялась в зависимости от Page?